# "Network request failed" and "XMLHttpRequest.chr.onerror" in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I using fetch in android react native for getting from my server below code:

```
fetch(apis.get_info, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic YYYYYYYY====='
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "user_id": "",
        "user_id_type": "",
        "kit_number": text,
        "channel": ""
    }),
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
                   console.log(responseJson)

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

[image: geting screen error]
but Sometimes get "Network request failed" and 
"XMLHttpRequest.chr.onerror"
What are your suggestions for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick but nice solution but I found it to be a 
catch(e){} Was.
The following works very well:

```
fetch(apis.get_info, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic YYYYYYYY====='
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    "user_id": "",
    "user_id_type": "",
    "kit_number": text,
    "channel": ""
}),
}).then((response) => response.json()).catch((error)=>{console.log('error)}})
.then((responseJson) => {
               console.log(responseJson)

})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```